# AICC multi-sco not working as expected in moodle

Tags: moodle, scorm

I have been working with AICC Multi-SCO in moodle. The multi-SCO zip file contains 3 SCOs those are SCO1,SCO2 and SCO3. After importing into moodle, it showing only one SCO which is the last one(SCO3). I am using moodle 2.7.3 version, linux OS.

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Note: if i upload my Multi-SCO zip file into https://cloud.scorm.com/. It is showing all the three SCO properly in the listing menu.

Thanks,
Thavaprakash.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your AICC package files.  They should be like a AU, CRS, CST and DES style file set.  

If you are using a imsmanifest.xml sounds like your using SCORM so that should have the version of SCORM within the XML.

Moodle never added SCORM 2004 (1.3) support so just verify your on 1.2 as a general tip.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for your response. Please find the AICC package zip file from the below drop box link. We are trying use AICC/HACP with moodle environment.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uucwuenid9cxs02/myCourse.zip?dl=0

Note: if you want to simulate issue in moodle, please use this link http://demo.moodle.net/.

Thanks,
Thavaprakash. S

Answer (score 0):

myCourse.CST appears to be missing a ending quote after "Developer_ID  - see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/Training/Training_AICCSiebAdm4.html#wp999600

myCourse.AU don't see anything wrong.

Rest looks fine.

Been a long time since I had to play with that.  Thanks for the refresher ;)

Comment: Thanks Mark, Sorry for late reply.